# Chazekes Kashrus - Permitted or Required to rely on it?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, halacha

Is the concept of "chazekes kashrus" (presumption of being acceptable), particularly with respect to the kashrus of food, a reshus (permission) or a chiyuv (obligation)?

I.e. are we required to rely on someone with chazekes kashrus or are we allowed to?

Comment: Unclear intent as to practical application of either side of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the fact that the food is kosher does not mean that you have to eat it :)  However, the halachah tells us how to determine whether a certain food item is kosher: if an otherwise observant Jew tells us that it is kosher, it is determined to be so.

There are two principal exceptions to chezkas kashrus:

1) If you have *personal* knowledge that the Jew who testified is not observant or otherwise not reliable, then you may not rely on his testimony that the food is kosher.  This does *not* extend to believing unsubstantiated rumors about someone else, which probably run into the category of lashon hara in the first place.

2) If the person who is testifying is incapable of properly determining the veracity of his testimony.  For example, if a person who has no knowledge of how to properly check vegetables for infestation tells you that he has cleaned the vegetable, there is no reason - or permission - to believe his "testimony".  The same would apply to someone who follows different standards of kashrus; for example, someone who keeps yoshon might not eat food with an otherwise reliable hechsher if that hechsher does not determine whether products are yoshon.

Comment: It seems to me the later part of number one actually helps the question along, it seems to me, in general while we are not allowed to ACCEPT unsubstantiated rumors we may and perhaps should take precaution lest it is true?

Answer (score -1):

You obviously do not mean to ask that if faced with a situation in which someone with a *hezkas Kashrus* wants us to eat his food and will be insulted if we don't, we must back off of our *humrah* and be *mahmir* on *V'ahavta L'rei'acha Kamocha* (love your fellow Jew as yourself), and (poor us) eat the food? Or are we allowed to stand our ground even though we will make him feel bad because, after all, *hezkas kashrus* is just *reshus* (or is it *rishus*?)?

Comment: Oddly enough I don't ask questions to be mocked and be dan l'kaf chov. V'Ahavta L'rei'acha kamocha

Comment: While I think that this answer should at most have been a comment on the question, I don't see its light tone as mocking you, Yirmeyahu. I think that Yahu just saw an opportunity to make a pun or two in the course of trying to flesh out what you're getting at with your question. I think that your question is an interesting point of theory at the very least and deserves serious consideration. If we can get some more community attention and analysis as a result of this exchange, so much the better.

Comment: Isaac, I doubt that Yahu meant to personally insult me, but its mocking a derisive. If he has sources for his points and presented them in a better way we might have a serious contender for an answer, but as it stands...

Comment: Yirmiyahu, it was not meant to mock in the slightest. I actually was clueless as to the intent of your question and in thinking about it came up with that scenario as a possible "nafka minah" but never even entertained that it was seriously the scenario you were thinking about. Your reputation (and I don't mean just points) and your dedication to truth speak for themselves on this website. Like Isaac said, I was fooling around with a couple of puns and at the same time trying to figure out what the practical application of your question would be.

Comment: And, Yirmiyahu, I am very sorry I offended you. If you can please point out exactly what you want me to change or remove, or if you want me to remove the entire answer and I will gladly do so!

Comment: I see you have already made edits, which are in my opinion appropriated. I'm not going to nit pick further. Nevertheless as far as the answer goes I would argue you have presented a faulty dilemma. Chazekes Kashrus is a great and necessary concept but it isn't, strictly speaking, the only way we generally make judgments. I'm sure that kashrus aside there are people who are shomer shabbos and kashrus whose middos, mitzvos observance, and or sechel are such you wouldn't be comfortable letting your child stay the night at their house. Just an example. I'd continue but i'm running out of space.

Comment: True! I was thinking just along the lines of the Kashrus issue. Of course there are other elements to take into consideration and if V'ahavta Lireiacha is mitigated by those issues, of course they may create a scenario in which one's hezkas kashrus does not make a difference. You were not nit picking. After your comments I could see how my "answer" could easily be taken as caustic. My sincere apoligies.

Comment: Yirmiyahu, in your previous comment you answered your own question: Of course Hezkas Kashrus is not a hiyuv if you are allowed to consider other factors regarding eating/sending children there.

Comment: Yahu, an answer without sources isnt' an answer. :)

Comment: Do you mean to tell me you have an actual "hava aminah" that once someone has a hezkas kashrus regarding kosher laws you would not be allowed to consider other factors besides kashrus when eating there? You yourself said there are other issues and I'm sure some of those you alluded to involve potential issurim and bitul of mitzvos, both di'oraisa and dirabanan. I believe that for such a hava amina one needs a source and not vice versa! :-)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you other than your claim that *I* gave an answer already. ;)

Comment: Gotcha! Have a Gr8 Shabbos!

Comment: BTW, my point is that for something so poshut, you don't need to run to a source! :-)